# How to hide options in a search listbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to hide the options in the list so that they only show as the person types. I've tried googling it and checking other questions on this website but I haven't found the answer I'm looking for.

Adele

Agnes

Billy

Bob

Calvin

Christina

Cindy

```
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
              var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
              input = document.getElementById("myInput");
              filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
              ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
                li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
                 for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                   a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                           li[i].style.display = "";
                  } else {
                       li[i].style.display = "none";

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please replace the image with actual code that creates the select. Easier to help.

Comment: I think you are likely looking for autocomplete funcionality. I suggest you to search for "auto complete" on google or here in StackOverflow and you will probably find something useful for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking for autocomplete then I think [Select2](https://select2.org/) can help.
Checkout this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kkqL7dqx/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" style='width: 150px'>
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="BR">Britain</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="DEL">Delhi</option>
  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
  <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
  <option value="LND">London</option>
  <option value="MAC">Macau</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks ! the thing is I don't want it to be a dropdown and search. But I'll look through the select 2 options, I appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

Check each option if it starts with the text in the textbox whenever textbox is changed, then hide elements that don't match

```js
var text='';
var count=0;
$(function() {
  $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
    count=0;
    text=$(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#listbox > option").each(function() {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().startsWith(text) && text != "") {
          count++;
          $(this).css("display","block");
        }
        else {
          $(this).css("display","none");
        }
    });

    if(count > 0) {
      $("#listbox").css("display","block");
    }
    else {
      $("#listbox").css("display","none");
    }

    if(count > 1) {
     $("#listbox").attr('size', count);
    }
    else {
     $("#listbox").attr('size', 2);
    }
  });
})
```

```css
textarea, select {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="searchbox"></textarea>
<br>
<select id="listbox" style="display: none" name="listbox" size="5">
  <option style="display: none">Ad</option>
  <option style="display: none">Ab</option>
  <option style="display: none">Bi</option>
  <option style="display: none">Bo</option>
  <option style="display: none">Ca</option>
  <option style="display: none">Co</option>
</select>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ypx1yyy/5/